# Retun WP_Query objects from shortcode atts array values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

Looking to return each occurrence (product) found in `name` where `name` is comma separated, e.g. `[woo_products_by_name name="shoe,shirt"]` If I do not `explode` `name` then nothing is returned as only `shoe,shirt` is seen. If `explode` is used then the query is not selective and it appears that all products are returned. If only `'name' => $name` is used and one verse two products as described above are specified, then the query works as expected. Would like to return a match for each item so in this example, to products would be returned.

```
function woo_products_by_name_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

        // Get attribuets
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'name' => ''
        ), $atts));
        //$name = explode(",", $atts['name']);

        ob_start();
        // Define Query Arguments
        $loop = new  WP_Query( array(
                'post_type'      => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'name'           => explode(",",$name)
        ));

        // Get products number
        $product_count = $loop->post_count;

        echo '<pre>'; print_r($loop->posts); echo '</pre>';
        return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode("woo_products_by_name", "woo_products_by_name_shortcode");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a very light SQL request that will gives product IDs for your product slugs. Then using `WP_Query` `post__in` argument, you will get what you expect:

```
function woo_products_by_name_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

    // Get attribuets
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'name' => ''
    ), $atts));

    if( empty($name) ) return;

    // Format product slugs string
    $name = str_replace(",", "','", $name);

    global $wpdb;
    // Get the corresponding products ids
    $ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
        WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_name IN('$name')" );

    ob_start();

    // Define Query Arguments
    $loop = new  WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__in'       => $ids
    ));

    // Get products number
    $product_count = $loop->post_count;

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($loop->posts); echo '</pre>';

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode("woo_products_by_name", "woo_products_by_name_shortcode");
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

---

Testing output in html/php:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( "[woo_products_by_name name='shoe,shirt']" ); ?>
```

Testing output in Wordpress text editor:

```
[woo_products_by_name name='shoe,shirt']
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would use the `id` or other queryable attribute in your shortcode instead, the query would be much easier if you did - but defeats the `get_by_name` methodology.

You're probably looking at running two separate queries within a `foreach` loop, or better yet drop the `WP_Query` and instead use [`get_page_by_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/)

```
function woo_products_by_name_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

    // Get attribuets
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'name' => ''
    ), $atts));

    $name_array = explode(",", $atts['name']);

    ob_start();

    $products = array();
    foreach( $name_array as $product ){
        $products[$product] = get_page_by_path( $product, OBJECT, 'product' );
    }

    // Get products number
    $product_count = count( $name_array );

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($products); echo '</pre>';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode("woo_products_by_name", "woo_products_by_name_shortcode");
```

Since you mentioned the need for using WP_Query, you'll be resorting to getting the id's either by using the `$wpdb` class with an sql query, and then running WP_Query with those IDs - or you can get the ID's from `get_page_by_path` and query those using the [`post__in`](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) argument (note the double underscore)

```
function woo_products_by_name_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

    // Get attribuets
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'name' => ''
    ), $atts));

    $name_array  = explode(",", $atts['name']);
    $product_ids = array();

    foreach( $name_array as $product ){
        $product = get_page_by_path( $product, OBJECT, 'product' );
        $product_ids[] = $product->ID;
    }

    ob_start();
    // Define Query Arguments
    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'post__in'       => $product_ids
    ));

    // Get products number
    $product_count = $loop->post_count;

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($loop->posts); echo '</pre>';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode("woo_products_by_name", "woo_products_by_name_shortcode");
```

Comment: While this works, was looking to use `WP_Query` so that we might be able to query other fields using `s` to search for a word in the title or content. If best that I create a new question due to lack of clarity, happy to do so as this is technically a correct answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a method of getting the `id` by sticking with `get_page_by_path`, and then looping through posts with those `id`'s using the `post__in` argument for `WP_Query`. It's not exactly pretty but it should work. The gist being you need to get a queryable parameter from the name whether it's via `$wpdb` or a built in function like `get_page_by_path`

Comment: This worked and thank you for the answer but I was looking for what you suggested where you leverage a `$wpdb` query in order to get the ID and then run the respective `WP_Query`